# Which of the following sets form a group under mutliplication modulo $14$?

Tags: group-theory

Which of the following sets form a group under mutliplication modulo 14?

1. $\{1,3,5\}$
2. $\{1,3,5,7\}$
3. $\{1,7,13\}$
4. $\{1,9,11,13\}$

I figured that only $\{1,3,5\}$ forms a group. But my answers say that that one is also wrong because 1) $3x3=9$ so $9$ should be in there as well and 2) $5\times5=11 \mod 14$ and $5$ is in there but $11$ is not. Could someone explain this reasoning to me please?

Comment: It looks like you have a perfectly fine explanation right there. What do you find difficult about it? (To start with, if you think that $\{1,3,5\}$ is a group, why doesn't the same thinking lead you to think that $\{1,3,5,7\}$ is one?)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: The set of all congruence classes relatively prime to the modulus number, say $n$, form a group under multiplication called the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$. So, 2 and 3 cannot be true. Also, 1 and 4 are not closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

The invertible residue classes with respect to multiplication modulo $14$ are $1,3,5,9,11,13$, according with the fact that
$$
\varphi(14)=\varphi(2)\varphi(7)=6
$$

This immediately excludes 2 and 4, because subsets of a finite group that are closed under multiplication are subgroups.

For 1, consider $3^2=9$.

For 3, note that $7$ is not invertible.

---

You can also consider the fact that proper subgroups can only have order $1$, $2$ or $3$. Since
$$
3^2=9,\quad 3^3\equiv 13\pmod{14}
$$
you know that $3$ has order $6$, so it's a generator of the whole group. Therefore the only proper subgroups are
$$
\{1\}, \{1,13\}, \{1,9,11\}
$$

Comment: However, the question didn't ask about _subgroups_ of $\mathbb Z^\times_{14}$, but just about _subsets_ of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,13\}$ that happen to be groups under multiplication modulo 14. So since $7\cdot 7\equiv 7\pmod{14}$ and $8\cdot 8\equiv 8\pmod{14}$, at least also $\{7\}$ and $\{8\}$ are groups under this operation -- as well as $\{8,6\}$ and $\{8,2,4\}$ and $\{8,10,2,6,4,12\}$, which are cyclic groups with $8$ as the identity.

Comment: @HenningMakholm All of the considered subsets contain $1$.

Comment: That is true -- my main point is to prevent the OP (and other readers) from concluding too much from this answer. When you jump directly to considering invertible elements of $\mathbb Z_{14}$, it can easily be read as implying that the only way to have a group under multiplication modulo $n$ is for it to consist of such element.

Answer (score 0):

For one of the sets to be a group, you need to check if any multiplication of set elements (modulo 14) is again in the set and every element is invertible. More formally:
$S$ is a group if and only if the following hold:

1. for all $a,b \in S$ it is true that $a \cdot b \mod 14 \in S$
2. for all $a \in S$ there exists a $b \in S$ such that $ab = 1$.

The set $\lbrace 1, 7, 13 \rbrace$ is closed under multiplication, but $7$ has no inverse element: $7 * 7 \equiv 7 \mod 14$ and $7 * 13 \equiv 7 \mod 14$.

For the first two sets you already have the answer.

For the last set you get $9 * 13 \mod 14 \equiv 5$ which is not in $\lbrace 1, 9, 11, 13\rbrace$.

Comment: @lhf: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: For an inverse element it is not required that $ab=1$ specifically -- instead $ab$ must be _the group's identity element_. For example, $\{8,2,4\}$ is a group under multiplication modulo $14$, with $8$ being the identity element and $2$ and $4$ being each other's inverses because $2\cdot 4=8$.

Comment: So a better reason why $\{1,7,13\}$ can't be a group under this operation is that it doesn't satisfy the cancellation law (which is implied by the group axioms): $7\cdot 7\equiv 7\cdot 1\pmod{14}$, but $7\not\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$3\cdot 3=9\equiv_{14}9\notin\{1,3,5\}$;

$3\cdot 3=9\equiv_{14}9\notin\{1,3,5,7\}$;

$9\cdot 13=117\equiv_{14}5\notin\{1,9,11,13\}$.

We showed that the sets labelled as 1, 2 and 4 are not closed under multiplication mod 14, this is they are not groupoids, hence they cannot be groups.

Instead, $a\cdot b\mod 14\in\{1,7,13\}$, for all $a,b\in\{1,7,13\}$, this is set number 3 is closed under the operation. Inverse elements here:

$1\cdot 1=1\equiv_{14}1$ so $1$ is the inverse of itself;

$13\cdot 13=169\equiv_{14}1$ so $13$ is the inverse of itself.

But
$${7\cdot 1\not\equiv_{14}1,}\qquad{7\cdot 7\not\equiv_{14}1,}\qquad{7\cdot 13\not\equiv_{14}1,}$$
indeed $7$ has no inverse $\mod 14$ and $\{1,7,13\}$ is neither a group.